# Compare large text File in java line by line

Tags: java, string, file

Dear fellow developers I am doing a java program which compare two text files line by line, first text file has 99,000 lines and the other file has 1,15,000 lines. I want to read the files and compare in such a way so that if any line match between first file and second file it should print the match. I have written the code but it is taking almost 10 mins to complete as it is printing due to for loop. How to make it fast, efficient and memory optimize. How to make it quickly executable?Please guide me. Thanks

```
public class Main {

static final String file1 = "file1.txt";
static final String file2 = "file2.txt";

static BufferedReader b1 = null;
static BufferedReader b2 = null;

static List<String> list_file1 = null;
static List<String> list_file2 = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    list_file1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list_file2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    String lineText = null;

    try {
        b1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        while ((lineText = b1.readLine()) != null) {
            list_file1.add(lineText);
        }
        b2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
        while ((lineText = b2.readLine()) != null) {
            list_file2.add(lineText);
        }
        compareFile(list_file1,list_file2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void compareFile(List<String> list_file1, List<String> list_file2) {
    for(String content1:list_file1){
        for(String content2:list_file2){
            if(content1.equals(content2)){
                System.out.println("Match Found:-"+content1);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If the code works, you should ask it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If your code already works, but you just want to improve it, then your question might fit better on out sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Thanks for commenting.. I will post there.

Comment: you do not need to create list to store all lines, just compare the current line of each file and store if there is a match. It will reduce your memory footprint and should help in performance., E.g:             b1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
            b2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
            while (((lineText = b1.readLine()) != null) && ((lineText = b2.readLine()) != null)) {
                //compare the lines here and store if they match
            }

Comment: @akshayapandey your approach only works if both files have same number of lines and only one occurrence of match is there. Here, there can be multiple occurrence possible and have to match all the occurrence and print whenever match is happen.

Answer (score 0):

use `HashSet` and its `contains` method:

```
public class Main {

    static final String file1 = "/tmp/file1";
    static final String file2 = "/tmp/file2";
    static BufferedReader b1 = null;
    static BufferedReader b2 = null;
    static Set<String> list_file1 = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list_file1 = new HashSet<>();
        String lineText = null;
        try {
            b1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
            while ((lineText = b1.readLine()) != null) {
                list_file1.add(lineText);
            }
            b2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
            while ((lineText = b2.readLine()) != null) {
                if (list_file1.contains(lineText)) {
                    System.out.println("Match Found:-" + lineText);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

if files have duplicates, you can use `HashMap` instead:

```
public class Main {

    static final String file1 = "/tmp/file1";
    static final String file2 = "/tmp/file2";
    static BufferedReader b1 = null;
    static BufferedReader b2 = null;
    static HashMap<String, Integer> list_file1 = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list_file1 = new HashMap<>();
        String lineText = null;
        try {
            b1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
            while ((lineText = b1.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!list_file1.containsKey(lineText))
                    list_file1.put(lineText, 1);
                else
                    list_file1.put(lineText, list_file1.get(lineText) + 1);
            }
            b2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
            while ((lineText = b2.readLine()) != null) {
                if (list_file1.containsKey(lineText)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < list_file1.get(lineText); i++) {
                        System.out.println("Match Found:-" + lineText);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Files can have duplicates and allowed to have match multiple times. Thanks for your valuable effort.

Comment: one option could be to sort and compare. At algorithmically, it will be nlog*2 for sorting and n(items)*(comparison)logn for comparison, thus 3*nlogn ~ n*logn. Thus, better than n^n which it has currently

Comment: @rackdevelop247 how exactly do you want duplicates to be treated? For example, if the first file has the line "hello" 2 times and the second file has "hello" 3 times, how many times do you want "hello" to appear in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like following. I have remove one iteration of your code still there can have duplicates. Here I use java 8 stream.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String file1 = "file1.txt";
  final String file2 = "file2.txt";
  BufferedReader b1;
  BufferedReader b2;

  List<String> list_file1 = new ArrayList<>();

  String lineText;

  try {
    b1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
    while ((lineText = b1.readLine()) != null) {
      list_file1.add(lineText);
    }
    b2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
    while ((lineText = b2.readLine()) != null) {
      final String text = lineText;
      list_file1.stream().filter(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(text)).forEach(s -> System.out.println("Match Found:-" + text));
    }
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following prints the lines in the same order as in your own code: i.e. if file 1 has the lines "one", "two" in that order and file 2 has the lines "two", "one" in that order, then the output will be "one", "two". To do that, we first read file 2 and build a map of lines and number of occurrences of each line:

```
static void printDuplicateLines(String filename1, String filename2) throws IOException {

    // Index the lines of file 2 with a map of line -> count
    Map<String, Integer> linesOfFile2 = new HashMap<>();
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename2))) {
        lines.forEach(line -> linesOfFile2.merge(line, 1, (oldValue, x) -> oldValue + 1));
    }

    // Check file 1 to see which lines are duplicate
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename1))) {
        lines.forEach(line -> {
                    int countOccurrencesInFile2 = linesOfFile2.getOrDefault(line, 0);
                    for (int i = 1; i <= countOccurrencesInFile2; i++)
                        System.out.println("Match Found:-" + line);
                }
        );
    }
}
```

We then just read file 1 line by line, find out how many occurrences there are of that line in file 2 (or 0 if none) and print the line that many times.

Note the use of try-with-resources to ensure the files are properly closed.